# Moving files with spaces in name batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

So I'm trying to mimic some features of Apple

One feature I am currently working on is being able to select a single or multiple files then through the "context menu" creating a "new folder" (directed to a batch file passing along file through FOR loop) then moving the files into that "new folder"

The issue I am having is with file names with spaces I researched using "robocopy" but finding it tricky alittle tricky

My code so far

```
@echo off
set cDir=%~dp1
set newFolder="%cDir%NewFolder"
md %newFolder%
echo.
:: get each selected file and echo
for %%I in (%*) do (
    echo %%I
    echo.
    echo %newFolder%
    move "%%I" "%newFolder%"
    echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: your `%newFolder` already contains the quotes; so there is no need to  add them again with the `move`command.

Comment: Use `~` modifier as follows: `move "%%~I" %newFolder%` or `move "%%~I" %newFolder%\ `. Read [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Thank you JosefZ & Stephan fixed it now it runs perfectly. Thank you again JosefZ for the reference

Comment: Hey Stephan or Josef I am trying to further expand this functionality to be able to move directories and its content as well do you know how I can achieve that using the code I presented ( with your updates )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified code should move files and folders as well. To be on the safe side, here is my variant of your code. Note quotation changes in `set`, `md` and `move` statements but I repeat: your (modified) variant of quotation should work as well:

```
@echo off
set cDir=%~dp1
set "newFolder=%cDir%NewFolder"
md "%newFolder%"
echo.
:: get each selected file and echo
for %%I in (%*) do (
    echo %%I
    echo.
    echo %newFolder%
    move "%%~I" "%newFolder%\"
    echo.
)
pause
```

Although `move /?` says *Moves files and renames files and directories*, both Source and Target may be either a *folder* or a single file ([resource](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html), verified on my Win-8).

Proof.

```
==>move "D:\Path\COCL\bu bu bu" "D:\Path\content\"
        1 dir(s) moved.

==>move "D:\Path\content\bu bu bu" "D:\Path\COCL\"
        1 dir(s) moved.

==>
```

Next resource: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Ok, now it is working. Thank you,, for everything Josef! I like the site ss64 for expanding my knowledge on CMD commands.